# mysql query join two tables group by and get sum

Tags: mysql

It's about get sum product's quantity and name from joined orders grouped by date

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orderproduct` (
  `id` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quantity` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fk_orders_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
INSERT INTO `orderproduct` (`id`, `quantity`, `name`, `fk_orders_id`) VALUES
(1, 3, 'Boulgour de bléss', 1),
(2, 2, 'Casarecce d\'épeautre', 1),
(3, 1, 'Cerneaux de noix', 1),
(5, 2, 'Boulgour de bléss', 3),
(6, 2, 'Casarecce d\'épeautre', 3),
(7, 4, 'Casarecce d\'épeautre', 4),
(8, 4, 'Cerneaux de noix', 4);
```

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, '2020-06-29 17:02:11'),
(3, '2020-06-29 10:56:47'),
(4, '2020-06-30 11:20:24');
```

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

the exemple with the order grouped by date and make a sum from his same product quantity:

order 29/6

- **productsA** quantity=1
- productsB quantity=2
- productsC quantity=3

order 29/6

- **productsA** quantity=4

order 30/6

- productsA quantity=1
- productsB quantity=2

My knowledge of mysql is to basic here wath i have tried for the moment:

```
SELECT      o.date, p.name, sum(p.quantity)
FROM       `orders` o , `orderproduct` p
WHERE       p.fk_orders_id = o.id
GROUP BY    p.name
```

The sum of quantities are grouped by product but dont know how take care of grouping by orders date.
I tried also some sub query
(i know this not working because sub Q; return more than 1 row and shoul be used witn 'IN' but it is just for illustrate the idéé):

```
select o.date,p.name, (
                SELECT      sum(p.quantity)
                FROM        `orderproduct` p
                GROUP BY    p.name
                )
FROM  `orders` o , `orderproduct` p
WHERE p.fk_orders_id = o.id
```

Desired result could be:
order.date  productname product.sumQuantity (name field)

2020-06-29 'Boulgour de bléss' 5, 'Casarecce d'épeautre' 4, 'Cerneaux de noix' 1

2020-06-30 'Casarecce d'épeautre' 4, 'Cerneaux de noix' 4,

Comment: Please provide a sample data set and desired result

Comment: use [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Data script for `orderproduct` is wrong/damaged. `quantity` in most rows is lost.

Comment: can you try this:  select o.date,p.name, sum(s.prosum)
FROM  `orders` o , `orderproduct` p,(
                SELECT      name, sum(p.quantity) prosum
                FROM        `orderproduct` p, `orders` o where p.fk_orders_id = o.id
                GROUP BY    p.name
                ) s
WHERE p.fk_orders_id = o.id and p.name=s.name group by o.date,p.name

Comment: Sorry updated orderproduct script and added data set and result

Comment: SELECT date(o.date) date ,p.`name`, sum(p.`quantity`) from orderproduct p, orders o where o.id=p.fk_orders_id GROUP by date(o.date),p.name

Comment: @MdRanaHossain many thanks work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @MdRanaHossain for the solution

```
SELECT date(o.date) date, p.name, sum(p.quantity) 
from orderproduct p, orders o 
where o.id = p.fk_orders_id 
GROUP by date(o.date), p.name
```